# Battery management for 12-24V motors

Tags: batteries, motor, 12v, 24v, power-management

We have 4 12-24V motors which we want to connect to a [14,8V battery](https://www.gensace.de/tattu-10000mah-14-8v-25-50c-4s1p-lipo-battery-pack.html). Two of the motors are position controlled (M3 and M4, see figure) and will not draw much current as they will mainly be stationary. The two other motors (M1 and M2, see figure) will be moving all the time but with some short spikes in the load (and thus draw more current). Between the motors (M1 and M2) and the battery, we have a [Roboclaw 2 x 60A Motorcontroller](https://www.basicmicro.com/RoboClaw-2x60A-Motor-Controller_p_8.html). This is supposed to tolerate as much as 34V. In the specifications, the motor controller is said to have a Battery Protection feature, whatever that means.

Until now we have only powered the circuit with an AC/DC power source but now we want to use the battery. So the question is: Do we need some kind of battery management system or can we just replace the AC/DC power source and connect it as it is?

[image: Schematics]

Unfortunately, we don't have any specifications on motors M1 and M2, but we have never experienced that they draw more current than 40A when we have applied 14 V to them.

Could, for instance, the situation when the batteries are closed to empty cause damage to the circuit?

Comment: Do you have a 12V battery? If so, 12VDC is 12VDC as long as the battery can source that much current.

Comment: Ok, so even if the current varies a lot it shouldnt be a problem if the battery can scource that much current?

Comment: What happends if the motor tries to use more current than the battery can deliver?

Comment: Depends on the battery type. At best, nothing happens other than it heating up due to internal resistances. Worst case - li-ion- it burns up. Check what the discharge rate of the battery is. If it's 1C, it can discharge its entire capacity in 1 hour. 2C, 30 minutes, etc...

Comment: Thanks for good advice! I will update you when I have tried to connect the battery.